# insert multiple data rows with checkboxes laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I had a table form where I will add multiple users in table and it has checkboxes. My problem is on the checkboxes.

User 1: ✓ Add, ✓ Edit, ✓ Delete 
User 2: ✓ Add, Edit, Delete

Expected Output in Database

```
Full Name | Permissions
John Doe  | ["Add", "Edit", "Delete"]
Jane Doe  | ["Add"]
```

What is inserted in the DB

```
Full Name | Permissions
John Doe  | "Add"
Jane Doe  | "Edit"
```

blade html

```
<button type="button" id="addUser">Add</button>
<table id="userTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Add</th> 
            <th>Edit</th> 
            <th>Delete</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS Code

```
$("#addUser").click(function () {
    t.row.add(['', 
        '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullname[]">',
        '<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="Add" data-parsley-multiple="status">',
        '<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="Edit" data-parsley-multiple="status">',
        '<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="Delete" data-parsley-multiple="status">',
    ]).draw(false); 
});
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->fullname as $key=>$insert) 
    {   
        $user = [
            'fullname' => $request->fullname[$key],
            'permissions' => json_encode($request->permissions[$key]),
        ];

        DB::table('users')->insert($user);
    }
}
```

In my code, `$request->permissions[$key]` is only getting 1 value per permission. How can I get all the checked value of permission in one user row and to be inserted for that user.

Comment: Add a unique index for every user in your input name attibute `name="permissions[' + index +']"` create `var index` every time you add a user, and make sure it is unique

Comment: Because for one fullname you are getting more than one permission. For example if your $key is 1 your permissions are not stored in 1 index. They are like 1, 2, 3. For `fullname[2]` they are 4,5,6 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add indexes to your input names, so they are grouped per user:

```
    $("#addUser").click(function () {
    var index = $(".user-name-field").length;
    t.row.add(['', 
        '<input class="form-control user-name-field" type="text" name="fullname[' + index + ']">',
        '<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[' + index + '][]" value="Add" data-parsley-multiple="status">',
        '<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[' + index + '][]" value="Edit" data-parsley-multiple="status">',
        '<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="permissions[' + index + '][]" value="Delete" data-parsley-multiple="status">',
    ]).draw(false); 
});
```

In this case i've added a class to the user name field, count these fields  to create the index

Comment: There is no need any index for `fullname`. For each loop there will be only one. And your index should start from 0. Not from length(which is at least 1)+1=2.

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli this way the key from the name is the same as the permissions, that  makes it easier to link the name to the permissions in the controller. With the current controller code, the `$key` must be the same. The Array index starts from count because there can be existing users in the view to start with

Comment: `permission['index']` can not hold more than 1 value inside. You should have fullname without index and permissions like: `permissions['+index+'][]`. **And index shoud start from 0**.

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli indeed, edited, my bad. 'index should start from 0' ? You could remove the +1, but still it is not needed when using a foreach. The count is needed because of existing users in the db.

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli i removed the +1 so it initially starts from 0. I can agree coding standards say to start array indexes from 0, but it does work fine when starting from 1

Comment: `$key` param in foreach starts from 0. Thats why it is better to start from 0. Good job anyway.

Comment: `$key` does not start from 0 when using foreach, in a foreach, a key kan be whatever you want. but still, i agree on using coding standards, if you have a numeric array index its better to start from 0